# How to maintain an infinite loop with multiple buttons?

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, infinite

Alright so basically what I am trying to do is load my GUI with three buttons, "Clear", "Calculate", and "Quit". Through an infinite for loop, when I press Calculate I want it to break the loop. I have the code for the button functionality but when I press Quit before I press Calculate I get a NullPointerException (The button still closes the GUI but I get an error). What do I have to do in order to get rid of this error?

Here's my code:

```
form = new BasicForm("Clear", "Calculate", "Quit");
buildForm();


for ( ; ; ) {
  button = form.accept();

  switch(button) {

    case 0:
      form.clearAll();
      break;

    case 1:
      // calculate code goes here
      break;

    case 2:
      form.close();
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: while (true) is better form than for(;;)

Comment: Some compilers produce warnings on while(true). It is a way to avoid warnings.

Comment: @JamesHutchinson they're exactly equivalent. Why would one be better than another?

Comment: In my opinion it is more readable for the developer who comes after you, but it's only an opinion I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will resolve your NPE error:

```
form = new BasicForm("Clear", "Calculate", "Quit");
buildForm();
boolean quitCalled=false;

for ( ; ; ) {
button = form.accept();

switch(button) {

case 0:
  form.clearAll();
  break;

case 1:
  // calculate code goes here
  break;

case 2:
  form.close();
  quitCalled = true;
  break;
}
if(quitCalled)
{
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.cosc.brocku.ca/sites/all/files/documentation/Brock_packages/BasicIO/BasicForm.html), you'll see that `BasicForm.close()` releases the resources used by the form, and that **the form should not be used thereafter**. But after you hit Quit, your loop restarts, and you try to call `form.accept()` again.

You need to break out of the loop when you handle Quit.

Comment: Yeah, I just wasn't too sure of how to break out of the loop. Didn't think of using a boolean and killing it when I use form.close(); , thank you for your help